# multi-conditional statement by group

Tags: r

I've got a simple dataset.

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), Primrely = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Primset = c(-4L, -3L, 1L, 2L, -4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, -4L, -2L, -3L, 3L), Primvalue = c(45L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 53L, 
45L, 44L, 65L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 5L), Secrely = c(5L, 7L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L), Secset = c(-3L, 1L, 
2L, -2L, -3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Secvalue = c(38L, 
-2L, -1L, 8L, 46L, 38L, 37L, 58L, -6L, -2L, -6L, 5L, -2L), Desired = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Primary", 
"Secondary"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Primrely", 
"Primset", "Primvalue", "Secrely", "Secset", "Secvalue", "Desired"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

   ID Primrely Primset Primvalue Secrely Secset Secvalue   Desired
1   1        0      -4        45       5     -3       38      <NA>
2   1        2      -3         5       7      1       -2   Primary
3   1        1       1         6       2      2       -1      <NA>
4   1        1       2        15       1     -2        8      <NA>
5   2        1      -4        53       2     -3       46 Secondary
6   2        1       5        45       0      2       38 Secondary
7   2        3       3        44       4      5       37      <NA>
8   3        4       1        65       5      7       58      <NA>
9   4        4       2         1       1      7       -6      <NA>
10  4        3      -4         5       1      4       -2      <NA>
11  4        1      -2         1       1      3       -6      <NA>
12  5        2      -3        12       0      2        5   Primary
13  5        2       3         5       2      1       -2   Primary
```

For each `ID`, I'd like to select rows that meet the criteria `(Prim = primary, Sec = secondary)`: If `Primrely` is `0` or `2` and `Primset` is `-3:3`, select all rows for each `ID`. If no rows for a given `ID` meet the primary criteria, select rows that meet the secondary criteria `(Secrely is 0 or 2 and Secset is -3:3)`. Ideally, I'd like to add a column `(Desired)` that indicate which criteria was met `(primary/secondary/NA)`.

I've been working with `ifelse` and `if else` functions without much luck mainly because I don't know how to command `R` to ingore a given `ID` if the primary criteria was already met (eg `ID #1` meets the second criteria but doesn't need it because it already met the first criteria).  In other words, if a 'primary' shows up in a given ID, it trumps all the 'secondary' criteria that were met. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: should row 3 be secondary? I'm not sure where the grouping comes in. It seems like you want this by row regardless of ID. If you were grouping by id, all would be NA except the last ID which would be primary

Comment: No, because I'm doing this by ID.  So if an ID has a primary row anywhere in the group, it will be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly now:

(left in the steps to show you what I was doing, you can remove them and/or do this all in one step if you want)

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                      4L, 5L, 5L), Primrely = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Primset = c(-4L, -3L, 1L, 2L, -4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                             2L, -4L, -2L, -3L, 3L), Primvalue = c(45L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 53L, 
                                                                                                                   45L, 44L, 65L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 5L), Secrely = c(5L, 7L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L), Secset = c(-3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2L, -2L, -3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Secvalue = c(38L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -2L, -1L, 8L, 46L, 38L, 37L, 58L, -6L, -2L, -6L, 5L, -2L), Desired = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Primary", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Secondary"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Primrely", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Primset", "Primvalue", "Secrely", "Secset", "Secvalue", "Desired"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))


within(dat, {
  Desired_step1 <- ifelse(Primrely %in% c(0,2) & Primset %in% -3:3,
                        1, ifelse(Secrely %in% c(0,2) & Secset %in% -3:3,
                                  2, 3))
  Desired_new <- factor(ave(Desired_step1, ID, FUN = function(x) 
    ifelse(x == min(x), x, NA)),
    levels = 1:3, labels = c('Primary', 'Secondary', 'NA'))
  Desired_step1 <- c('1'='Primary','2'='Secondary','3'=NA)[Desired_step1]
})


#    ID Primrely Primset Primvalue Secrely Secset Secvalue   Desired Desired_new Desired_step1
# 1   1        0      -4        45       5     -3       38      <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
# 2   1        2      -3         5       7      1       -2   Primary     Primary       Primary
# 3   1        1       1         6       2      2       -1      <NA>        <NA>     Secondary
# 4   1        1       2        15       1     -2        8      <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
# 5   2        1      -4        53       2     -3       46 Secondary   Secondary     Secondary
# 6   2        1       5        45       0      2       38 Secondary   Secondary     Secondary
# 7   2        3       3        44       4      5       37      <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
# 8   3        4       1        65       5      7       58      <NA>          NA          <NA>
# 9   4        4       2         1       1      7       -6      <NA>          NA          <NA>
# 10  4        3      -4         5       1      4       -2      <NA>          NA          <NA>
# 11  4        1      -2         1       1      3       -6      <NA>          NA          <NA>
# 12  5        2      -3        12       0      2        5   Primary     Primary       Primary
# 13  5        2       3         5       2      1       -2   Primary     Primary       Primary
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question - I'd like any primary criteria to trump all secondary criteria for a given ID. For instance, with your code, it calls for secondary in row 3 however because there is a primary in ID #1, all secondaries should be NA. For ID #1, it should be NA, Primary, NA, NA

Comment: that's what the `ave(..., FUN = min)` was for. the `Desired_new` column is not what you want? It is just what you have for `Desired` but spread out for the number of rows per id

Comment: Not quite because I'm using the 'Primary' to extract the Primvalue and I don't need the Primvalues that do not meet the criteria. For instance, in ID #1, I'd be interested in extracting Primvalue 5, not the others.

Comment: okay, I made a minor change to the `ave` function, what about now

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick & dirty solution assuming your `data.frame` is named `df`. You can refine it yourself I think:

```
df$Desired <- ifelse((df$Primrely==0 | df$Primrely==2) & (df$Primset >= -3 & df$Primset <= 3),
                     "Primary",
                     NA)

idx <- is.na(df$Desired)
df$Desired[idx] <- ifelse((df$Secrely[idx]==0 | df$Secrely[idx]==2) & (df$Secset[idx] >= -3 & df$Secset[idx] <= 3),
                          "Secondary",
                          NA)
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question - I'd like any primary criteria to trump all secondary criteria for a given ID.  For instance, with your code, it calls for secondary in row 3 however because there is a primary in ID #1, all secondaries should be NA.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So just group by ID afterwards and set all other entries to NA in case you find a primary